# Can we live forever by uploading our brain information to a computer supplemented by a robot for a body, or no body at all?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computers, robots, brain

If you think about it, we ourselves are only information. So if we could find a reliable way of reading all this information stored within us, especially the information that makes up our brains, we could upload it.

I mean, theoretically speaking, we can upload this information in a computer (a computer designed for this purpose), and live forever. We just need to figure out how to make this computer learn more things like we do ourselves to increase our information.

One other thing would be, "Can we simulate creativity?"

Comment: Also worth noting: There are two questions here. One relating to uploading consciousness, and one relating to simulated creativity. Can you decide which question you'd rather ask here and move the other to a separate question?

Comment: @JoeBloggs No! both these questions compliment eachother. So I'd rather let them stay together.

Comment: @ITguy Try editing your question to refer to the other question on the possibility of a computer upload and then expand it by asking your question about creativity.

Answer (score 2):

[Computational modeling of higher cognitive functions has only recently begun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_neuroscience). No one knows yet whether a human mind could be completely transferred, or if the biological aspects (hormones etc) are still required. So I guess you could assume whatever is more convenient for your story?

But if by "simulate creativity" you mean "imitate the appearance of it", it's sort of done already:
[image: neural-network-dreams]
They [were made by a neural network](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html) that was forced to look for known patterns in a random-noise image, and amplify whatever it finds.
And [here](http://www.hexahedria.com/2015/08/03/composing-music-with-recurrent-neural-networks/) is some music, written by a neural network. It's not quite impressive and sometimes glitchy, but still surprisingly bearable.

Comment: The hormoses simply act on the parameters of the network elements and the other cells which regulate and direct the growth of the network proper. Its effects are physical and ultimately understandable and can be included in the artificial network implementation.